# Convert error between Expression and Delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, expression-trees

We can write below code:

```
 Func<string, string> func = x => x + x;
```

We also can write:

```
 Expression<Func<string, string>> exp = x => x + x;
```

But when I write :

```
Expression<Func<string, string>> exp = func;
```

The compiler throw an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func' to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

So I change the code as below:

```
  Expression<Func<string, string>> exp = (Expression<Func<string, string>>)func;
```

Same error as before.

So what's the real type of `x => x + x;` , what's the relation between Expression and Delegate/Lambda Expression?

Answer (score 6):

> So what's the real type of `x => x + x;`

It doesn't have one. A lambda expression is implicitly convertible into compatible delegate types and expression tree types (with some restrictions) but that decision is made at *compile-time*, and different code is generated depending on what the target of the conversion is.

You can convert from an expression tree to a delegate at execution time (using [`LambdaExpression.Compile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928(v=vs.110).aspx)) but you can't go the other way.

Basically, a lambda expression is a source representation of some logic. The compiler can either generate a code representation of that logic (conversion to delegate) or a data representation of that logic (conversion to expression tree). To be very specific, for expression trees, code is generated that will build the data representation.

Comment: I'm not sure this truly answers this question. You say at compile-time, but the type of func is known at compile time.

Comment: @LewsTherin: Yes, it is. But that's not the type of the lambda expression itself - that doesn't have a type. (Just like the `null` literal doesn't have a type, and anonymous methods, and method groups.)